# Haskell Lens: How to elegantly test list item

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

```
data Game = Game {
 _players :: [Player]
}

data Player = Player {
 _cards :: [Card]
}

data Card = Card {
 _status :: CardStatus
}

data CardStatus = Face | Back
```

Then I `makeLenses` on the above data types.

The game quit condition is that all the cards in a player's hand are Back.
So in my Game StateT monad, I access all the CardStatus and test them. Since I am new to Lens I'm wondering what's the elegant way to write this.
A little bit lost in the forest of Lens operators.

Comment: I do not really get what this has to do with lenses, you can define a function that tests if all the statusses are black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module [`Control.Lens.Fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html) has many combinators for testing targets of lenses/folds/traversals: [`has`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:has) (useful for checking that a prism matches), [`anyOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:anyOf), `noneOf`, [`allOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:allOf)...

In your example (assuming we have also [generated the prisms](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-TH.html#v:makePrisms) for `CardStatus`) we could do something like:

```
endGame :: Game -> Bool
endGame = anyOf (players.folded) (allOf (cards.folded.status) (has _Back))
```

Also, to find *which* players have winning hands, we could use [`filtered`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:filtered):

```
winners :: Fold Game Player
winners = players.folded.filtered (allOf (cards.folded.status) (has _Back))
```

These functions are analogous to typical list functions, but can be applied directly to folds, so they don't yank you out as much of the lensy world. For example, we could go on composing `winners` with another `Fold`.

Answer (score 3):

So you want an optic that tells you if all cards are `Back`. Morally

```
allBack :: Getter Player Bool
```

This would clearly be something of the form

```
allBack = cards . _
```

...don't even go any further, ask GHC if that makes any sense at all:

```
$ ghc wtmpf-file11136.hs
wtmpf-file11136.hs:26:19: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: (Bool -> f Bool) -> [Card] -> f [Card]
```

ok, sounds sensible enough. That signature looks suspiciously of good old

```
traverse :: (a -> f b) -> [a] -> f [b]
```

...which is indeed pretty much the archetype of the whole Van Laarhoven lens formalism, and very often useful when building actual lens composition chains. Clearly, we still need to focus in more, but first this:

```
allBack = cards . traverse . _
```

giving

```
wtmpf-file11136.hs:26:19: error:
    • Could not deduce (Applicative f) arising from a use of ‘traverse’
       ...

wtmpf-file11136.hs:26:30: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: (Bool -> f Bool) -> Card -> f Card
```

Ok, the problem here is that a `Getter` is supposed to immediately focus in on a single element. But actually, we first need to go over multiple elements to condense (*fold*) to a single `Bool`. That means we need to change the signature from `Getter` to `Fold` (which under the hood provides the `Applicative` constraint):

```
allBack :: Fold Player Bool
allBack = cards . traverse . _
```

```
    • Found hole: _ :: (Bool -> f Bool) -> Card -> f Card
        ...
    • No instance for (Monoid Bool) arising from a use of ‘allBack’
```

Ok, that makes sense – we specified that we want to somehow reduce over the list, but there is more than one way to reduce bools over a list. In our case, we want them *all to be true*, i.e. we need to switch from `Bool` to the [`All` monoid](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:All):

```
import Data.Monoid (All(..))

allBack :: Fold Player All
allBack = cards . traverse . _
```

```
wtmpf-file11136.hs:26:30: error:
    • Found hole: _ :: (All -> f All) -> Card -> f Card
```

Ok, that looks good. Now we need to specify *what property of a card* we want to check. Well, something about its status:

```
allBack = cards . traverse . status . _
```

```
    • Found hole: _ :: (All -> f All) -> CardStatus -> f CardStatus
```

At this point we now need a decision, i.e. we need to toss in a *prism*. One might think it's the `_Back` prism, but actually that represents the “boring” case. The case where we want to trigger a failure is `_Face`:

```
allBack = cards . traverse . status . _Face . _
```

```
    • Found hole: _ :: (All -> f All) -> () -> f ()
```

Here, all that remains to be done is announcing that this `_Face` is a failure case:

```
allBack = cards . traverse . status . _Face . like (All False)
```

That works, though as Willem Van Onsem commented going purely lens is not really optimal here. Just writing this as a *function* is more sensible, [danidiaz' suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49553366/745903) strikes a good balance.

Comment: Thanks for showing the thought process. You've just shown me a bunch of new stuff to learn.